# Bootstrap 4 Form Validation - Custom styling not working after checkValidity() call

Tags: html, validation, bootstrap-4

The form tag specifies **class="needs-validation"** and has the **novalidate** attribute to indicate custom validation.

When the code runs and displays the form, click the button with an empty text field and since it is required, it should display the message and style the field as red.

Validation is occurring by the call to **checkValidity()** and it is returning false for an empty field but the field is not styled as either **:invalid** nor **:valid**.

This is the doc about what I am attempting: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

Thanks

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function (e) {
        var form = $("#CertForm")[0];
        var isValid = form.checkValidity();
        if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
        return false; // For testing only to stay on this page
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.2.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Why neither feedback displays when clicking Submit?
  Also, the required txtName input field should be red if invalid
-->

<form id="CertForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
    <label for="txtName"> * Name:</label>
    <input id="txtName" required /> Blank for Invalid case
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a name</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
    <br />
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `form-control` class for you input element. As bootstrap says:

> Textual form controls—like `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`—are
>   styled with the .form-control class. Included are styles for general
>   appearance, focus state, sizing, and more.

By the way, you have not set an input type like "text".

Working code:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function (e) {
        var form = $("#CertForm")[0];
        var isValid = form.checkValidity();
        if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
        return false; // For testing only to stay on this page
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.2.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Why neither feedback displays when clicking Submit?
  Also, the required txtName input field should be red if invalid
-->

<form id="CertForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate="">
    <label for="txtName"> * Name:</label>
    <input id="txtName" class="form-control" type="text" required /> Blank for Invalid case
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a name</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
    <br />
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually had class="form-control-sm" on that input but apparently it needs to be "form-control" or both "form-control form-control-sm". I omitted the type="text" since that's the default.